unsolved reference color error while building a minecraft plugin for papermc
Here is my code:

import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor
import org.bukkit.util.Vector


class jumpCommand :CommandExecutor{
    override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, p2: String, p3: Array<out String>?): Boolean {
        if(sender is Player){
            if(sender.isOp){
                sender.sendMessage(Component.text("You jumped")).color(TextColor.color(0, 255, 75))
                sender.velocity = sender.velocity.add(Vector(5.0, 10.0, 5.0))
            }
            else{
                sender.sendMessage(Component.text("Nigga u dont got perms ma boy")).color(TextColor.color(255, 0, 0))
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

errors
unsolved reference color
It says it can't find color as reference im new to kotlin and tried following a tutorial but I can't seem to find any sort of solutions to this tried looking in the github repo of it still cant wrap my head around
I tried some different keyword they ended up not working either

Welcome to SO. Please add your stack trace (helps debugging) and review punctuation (just helps to read). Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Regarding you problem, CommandSender.sendMessage() returns void. Calling any method on void will not work. You probably want to set this on the Component instead.

You made a mistake. Here, the error comes from the call of color() that seems to be invalid.
If we focus on this line:
sender.sendMessage(Component.text("You jumped")).color(TextColor.color(0, 255, 75))

You're doing:

Component.text("You jumped")
sender.sendMessage(youJumped)
TextColor.color(0, 255, 75)
sendMsg.color(textColor)

If you check, you're trying to color the result of sendMessage. But it's too late, the message is sent. When building message, you should complete entirely the message before send it, like this:
sender.sendMessage(Component.text("You jumped").color(TextColor.color(0, 255, 75)))
// same as:
val comp = Component.text("You jumped").color(TextColor.color(0, 255, 75));
sender.sendMessage(comp)

(and it's the same remark for the second message)
